# join_by data-masking in dplyr in R

Tags: r, dplyr

How can I index to an ith column within `join_by`

```
a <- data.frame( a.1= 1:4 )
b <- data.frame( b.1= 1:4 )
inner_join( a, b, by= join_by( x$a.1 < y$b.1 )
```

Suppose we are using a larger data.frame with more columns a.n, how would i index the `join_by` columns with say a.i .

Data-masking with `filter`, columns can be indexed by name with say :

```
i <- 1
index.name <- paste0("a.", i )
filter( a, .data[[index.name]] < 3 )
```

and with `mutate` even :

```
mutate( a, "{index.name}" := .data[[index.name]] + 1 )
```

Furthermore, expressions formed by `expr <- expression()` can be passed to `filter()` with `filter( eval( expr ) )`. Can I create an expression such that `join_by` uses that expression:

```
expr <- expression( x$a.i < y$b.i )
inner_join( a, b, by= join_by( expr ) )
```

or something of the sort.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I'm not quite clear on the main goal -- do you specifically want to `join_by` an expression or is that one potential workaround for what you want to do? In the first case, you can just use `inner_join( a, b, by= join_by( a.1 < b.1 ))`...

Comment: Does this suffice? `i <- 1; a_var <- paste0("a.", i); inner_join( a, b, by= join_by( {{a_var}} < b.1 ))`?

Comment: @JonSpring Yes for my purposes, this does work, using `{{var_name}}`. I wanted to use expressions such that i could pass in it as a function argument. Say `function( a, b, expr ) { inner_join( a, b, join_by( expr ) %>% ... }`

Comment: This might potentially be an XY problem -- if your situation is that you have many numerically named columns in two data frames, and you are iterating through those to join them, it might be made a simpler problem if you pivot your data frames longer before the join.

Comment: @JonSpring Ahh yes i see, I hadn't thought of pivoting before. In particular I am actually doing a filtered cross join but with the inner_join. Pivoting the frame first could be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `glue()` we dynamically create the join condition string and parse it to an expression with `parse_expr()` from `rlang` package. The `!!` operator unquotes the expression in `join_by()`

```
library(rlang)
library(dplyr)

join_condition <- parse_expr(glue::glue("x${a_col} < y${b_col}"))
inner_join(a, b, by = join_by(!!join_condition))
```

```
  a.1 b.1
1   1   2
2   1   3
3   1   4
4   2   3
5   2   4
6   3   4
```

Answer (score 4):

```
library(dplyr)

i <- 1
a_var <- paste0("a.", i)
b_var <- paste0("b.", i)
inner_join(a, b, join_by({{a_var}} < {{b_var}}))
```

Result

```
  a.1 b.1
1   1   2
2   1   3
3   1   4
4   2   3
5   2   4
6   3   4
```

Comment: Even though this doesn't have as much power as [Tarjae's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77552546/22863450), this is very clean, useful and can also solve my problem. Thank you

Comment: I'm curious @jinTgreater, what about this has "less power"?

Comment: I presume there might be cases where the OP wants to control the `<` or use multiple join terms, and @TarJae's answer seems more flexible that way. I haven't figured out how to make mine more general yet, but it seems sufficient if we have a static comparison condition where the name of the columns is the only thing changing.

Comment: @r2evans @JonSpring , Precisely. With @Tarjae's , the join condition can be changed dynamically, not just the join variables, the join condition can be passed into a function as a string . I do recognise that doing lots of `parse_expr` isn't too pretty. Perhaps there might be a way to pass in the condition as an `expression`...